# HttpErrorResponse cannot access _listId from mongo db by using params ANGULAR

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, mean-stack

I am a beginner and i am following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOkAx1jZokc&list=PLIjdNHWULhPSZFDzQU6AnbVQNNo1NTRpd&index=5) on creating a task manager application with Angular. At around 26:00 we access listID via "params._listId" .In current version of Angular you can no longer access listId this way. In the comments of that video somebody suggests to use "params?.['_listId'] but that cause mongo db to crash and it gives me a httperror response  :

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: _HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/lists',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/lists: 0 Unknown Error',
  error: ProgressEvent2 {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest2 {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest2 {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: _HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map(0) {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map(0) {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/lists/undefined/tasks',
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/lists/undefined/tasks: 0 Unknown Error',        
  error: ProgressEvent2 {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest2 {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest2 {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}`
```

Here is my task-view.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TaskService } from '../../task.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrl: './task-view.component.scss'
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
  lists!: any[];
  tasks!: any[];
  
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        console.log(params);
        //this.taskService.getTasks(params?.['_listId']).subscribe((tasks: any) => {
        //this.tasks = tasks;
        //})
       
        
      }
    
      
    )

      this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: any) => {
      this.lists = lists;
      console.log(lists);
      })

  }

  

}
```

commented lines is what causes the issue. I tried changing "params._listId" to params?.['_listId'] but that causes mongo db to crash. I am sorry if i wasnt clear enough i am a beginner to these things.

Comment: The error specifies a route of `http://localhost:3000/lists/undefined/tasks`.  Passing `undefined` is likely your problem.  Try passing a known valid value instead of the params. ex: `taskService.getTasks('abc')`.  That should work, then you need to figure out why your param is undefined.  You are already logging out the params, so verify that your param matches what is shown in the output.